# How to set execute permission for firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that download some csv data.
When I try to execute the function in the browser

```
https://us-central1-my-project-prod.cloudfunctions.net/downloadSomecsv
```

The browser ask me for my google account. How can I set execute permission on the function, so I can call it from a href?

It's a very long function written in TS so I m only including the main part of it.

```
export const downloadSuppliersHttps = async (req: functions.Request, res: functions.Response): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    console.log('start downloadCsvHttps');
    const response = await new DownloadCsv().handle();
    res.setHeader(
      "Content-disposition",
      "attachment; filename=Supplieres.csv"
    );
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    res.send(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you share the code of your Cloud Function pls?

Comment: I added some of the code. Let me know if you need more information